# Best way to select row with following scenario using greenDao?

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I have **3 tables** :

```
    Manager: manager_id, taluka_name  
    Employee: employee_id, employee_manager_id   
    Target: target_id, target_employee_id
```

Now i have to show a ListView of all the targets **taluka_name** wise.
I am using greenDao for the interaction with the SQlite database.

**This is the process i have tried**, It is taking too long using the method i have used:

```
    Step1: Get Manager ID for the taluka name from the DB.
    Step2: Get Employee for the Target table->Employee ID.
    Step3: Get Manager ID from the Employee table.
    Step4: Compare if Both Manager ID are equal {if YES then target 
           belongs to that taluka}
```

**Below is the type of query i want to accomplish using Greendao**

```
        SELECT *
        FROM target t, location l, current c
        WHERE t.target_location_id = l.location_id
        AND t.target_location_id = c.school_id
        AND t.target_status <> '0'
        AND t.target_status <> '4'
        AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),t.target_exec_end_time)<7
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please provide some more details.

Comment: @greenrobot sir please give me some time i will, try to change the question and make it less confusing. Also thanks for the reply.

Comment: @greenrobot, Sir i have added the type of query i would like to accomplish using greendao.