# Greendao: insert, update, delete Syntax, Best practice

Tags: android, greendao

I have asked similar question here but i didnt got any satisfactory response, so please understand my concern:

```
    1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846105/insert-ot-update-using-one-of-the-field-as-key-in-greendao
    2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547288/best-way-to-select-row-with-following-scenario-using-greendao
```

I have a table called **"TARGET"** both on Server and Client.
Here Server is MySql and Client is Android.

I wanted to use **greendao** for the client part, 
I have multiple tasks todo that are as follows:

1. Employee with some **EMPLOYEE_ID** will get all the targets from the server after certain date, Now
   in the client part if the **TARGET** is present then it should be updated, else inserted.
   This is **insertOrUpdate** Case.
2. Delete certain target using **TARGET_ID.**
3. Get the list of TARGET's using the **TARGET_NAME**.

Data Regarding Question:

```
    TABLE : TARGET
    FIELDS: TARGET_ID
            TARGET_NAME
            EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Used below code in DaoExampleGenerator:
[Best way to select row with following scenario using greenDao?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547288/best-way-to-select-row-with-following-scenario-using-greendao)

```
    private static void addTarget(Schema schema){
        Entity target = schema.addEntity("TARGET");
        target.addStringProperty("TARGET_ID").primaryKey().autoincrement();
        target.addStringProperty("TARGET_NAME");
        target.addStringProperty("EMPLOYEE_ID");
    }
```

Below is what i have done for the questions i haved posted:

```
    1. tDao.insertOrReplaceInTx(tArrayList);
       where, tArrayList is ArrayList of TARGET Object.
    2. for deleting a target using TARGET_ID, i load all the targets in     
       ArrayList<TARGET> then check TARGET_ID of each TARGET object. If 
       the TARGET_ID matches then i use, **tDao.delete(t);**
    3. for this also i do the same as (2), i load all the targets then match 
       the TARGET_NAME, If it matches then i add it to list.
```

Can Anyone please tell me best possible ways to implement above problem statements.
using **greendao** ?

Comment: question makes no sense.

Comment: @MitchWheat Can you please tell me what exactly you understand. so that i can explain to you my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to build a delete query.  As the [GreenDao docs](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/queries/) say:

> Delete queries
>
> Bulk deletes do not delete individual entities, but all entities
>   matching some criteria. To perform bulk deletes, create a
>   QueryBuilder, call its buildDelete method, and execute the returned
>   DeleteQuery. This part of the API may change in the future, e.g.
>   convenience methods may be added etc. Keep in mind, that bulk deletes
>   currently do not affect entities in the identity scope, e.g. you could
>   “resurrect” deleted entities if they have been cached before and are
>   accessed by their ID (load method). Consider clearing the identity
>   scope for now, if that may cause issues for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that what you do now is the only answers of your questions ...
As far as I know there's no method in greenDao that gets rows by a criteria or delete a single row by criteria ... only by the ID (Long) ...